# How do I get data from entities that inherit others in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

new to EF - please bear with me.

Due to the way the database was designed, in my model I have a User entity.  The Contact entity inherits from the user entity, and the Profile entity inherits from the Contact entity.

How can I get a list of Profiles, and, how do I create a Profile?

I am able to get a list of Users no problem.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would like to know as well (also new to EF). With LINQ-to-SQL (over WCF for Silverlight 3) I NEVER used the generated objects, because I always end up wanting something more "advanced" than the framework has to offer (e.g. add or remove fields). Thus, I had a custom object for every DB object. This sounds like more work, but it is much less of a headache in the long run.

Comment: @Peet Brits - see my answer. I've done this exact same thing recently. Quite easy to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Entity Framework 4 Table-Per-Type Inheritance**, you need 2 things:

1. A "parent" table, and a "child" table. The "child" table should have a FK to the "parent" table's PK.
2. You need to setup an inheritance association in the EDM. If done correctly, you should see a arrowhead association between the entities, and the child table should have text in the name stating it's parent.

Now, you can get "Users" this way: (i assume you are already doing this)

```
var allUsers = ctx.Users;
```

Now getting "Contacts" is special - because it belongs to the "Users" entity set (you can prove this by looking at the properties for the "Contacts" entity).

This is how you get Contacts:

```
var allContacts = ctx.Users.OfType<Contact>();
```

How does that work? Well **OfType** is an IEnumerable extension method which filters all the elements based on a given type. So it's basically a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var item in source)
{
   if (item is Contact) result.Add(item);
}
```

Similarily, this is how you get Profiles:

```
var allProfiles = ctx.Users.OfType<Profile>();
```

To add a new Profile, again - add it to the "Users" entity set:

```
var newProfile = new Profile { Name = "Foo" };
ctx.Users.AddObject(newProfile);
```

On a side note, **i hope** these tables are not relating to the ASP.NET Membership schema. If they are, stop right now. You **should not** map these tables via EF. Access the functionality via the regular Membership API.

HTH.

Comment: if i try this: var allContacts = ctx.Users.OfType<Contact>;
, I get this error on allContacts: cannot assign method group to implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: My bad - you need the () at the end. `ctx.Users.OfType<Contact>()`. That will be an IQueryable, if you want a list, do this: `ctx.Users.OfType<Contact>().ToList();`